# What is the name of medical instruments for laparoscopy?

Tags: medical-device, instruments

When you look at the following image, you can see at least two types of medical instruments for laproscopy:

[image]

On the photo, there are:

- a scissor (the green one)
- tweezers (yellow and blue)

I've also seen:

- a "burner" (seems to be similar to a soldering-iron)
- a video camera which also has a light
- probably more

Answer (score 4):

The most important instrument is **laparoscope/endoscope** which is

> a fiberoptic instrument inserted through an incision in the abdominal wall and used to examine visually the interior of the peritoneal cavity. ([link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laparoscope))

Laparoscope is the instrument with video camera.

There are also:

- [veres needle](http://www.whonamedit.com/synd.cfm/3348.html) needed for draining fluids
- [trocar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trocar)
- insufflator for insufflation ([insufflation  looks like that](http://c8.alamy.com/comp/ADW7G3/laparoscopic-insufflation-of-the-abdomen-with-removal-of-adhesions-ADW7G3.jpg))

> Traditionally, the first step during laparoscopic surgery is to distend the abdomen, including entry into the abdomen and then **insufflation with a gas (pneumoperitoneum), providing sufficient operating space to ensure adequate visualization of the structures and manipulation of instruments** ([link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0051907/)).